# Error when directly setting pageIndex in page view controller

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

I'm using page view controller and table view. I want to go straight to the page when I select a cell in the table view. But, when I click on table view cell the app crashes.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'

This is my code..

** From PageViewLatestIssueController **

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

```
 [self.tv_tableOfContents deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];


  LatestIssueController *lic = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LatestIssueController"];

    if ([[self.arrayPages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@“13”]) {
        lic.pageIndex = 5;
        [lic goToPage];
    }else if([[self.arrayPages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"15"]){
        lic.pageIndex = 7;
        [lic goToPage];
    }else{
        ….
    }  
}
```

**From LatestIssueController **

-(void)goToPage{

```
    self.pageViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageViewLatestIssue"];
    self.pageViewController.dataSource = self;

    PageViewLatestIssueController *startingViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:self.pageIndex];
    NSArray *viewControllers = @[startingViewController];
    [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:nil];

    [self addChildViewController:self.pageViewController];
    [self.view addSubview:self.pageViewController.view];
    [self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
```

Comment: Code looks OK. Turn on debug all exception and test again.

Comment: the app still crashes when I select a cell in the tableview.